# Push-Location in Powershell not working the same as PUSHD in bat

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, python

**EDIT:** Alt title: New-PSDrive in Powershell not working the same as NET USE in bat

I'm trying to load a python script in WinPython off a UNC Path, so I need to map it to a drive.  I have all this working in a bat file but can't get it to work in Powershell.

bat(works):

```
NET USE P: "\\networkPath\WinPython\WinPython-32bit-3.6.1.0Zero"
PUSHD P:\
"P:\python-3.6.1\python.exe" "P:\loadRemix3D.pyw"
```

Powershell(fails):

```
New-PSDrive -Name P -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\networkPath\WinPython\WinPython-32bit-3.6.1.0Zero
Push-Location -Path P:\    
Start-Process -FilePath P:\python-3.6.1\python.exe -WorkingDirectory P:\python-3.6.1 -ArgumentList P:\loadRemix3D.pyw
```

The pathing is correct as in the Powershell correctly executes Python and loads the Python script, but the Python script's pathing behaves as though I loaded it directly from UNC.

How do I make the Powershell work the same as the bat?

**EDIT:**
As per Jeff's answer, here is a working version of the Powershell script:

```
NET USE P: "\\networkPath\WinPython\WinPython-32bit-3.6.1.0Zero"
Push-Location -Path P:\
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "P:\python-3.6.1\pythonw.exe" -WorkingDirectory "P:\python-3.6.1" -ArgumentList "P:\loadRemix3D.pyw"
NET USE P: /delete /y
```

The only other thing I needed to add was to explicitly delete the mapping since it appears that NET USE mappings persist in the global PowerShell context(?).

Comment: you could just add `-persist` to your `New-PSDrive`. This will send the PSDrive to your Filesystem. In some PowerShell Versions you also would need to specify `-scope Global`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drives created using Powershell's FileSystem provider (i.e., `New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem`) are not visible to "outside" processes, and get 'expanded' to their root when passed to such an outside process. Instead, use the same `NET USE` command that you do for the batch version of the program.